# Modificar estado :focus desde HTML

Tags: html, css

Quería modificar el estado `:focus` de un elemento *HTML* desde la propia etiqueta *HTML*. Me explico, por ejemplo puedo definir los estilos en la propia etiqueta:

```
<div style='background: grey'>
</div>
```

Que en *CSS* sería equivalente a poner:

```
div {
   background: grey;
}
```

El problema es que no sé cómo modificar los estilos con los atributos `:focus` o `:hover`. En *CSS* sé que sería lo siguiente:

```
div:hover {
    color: white;
}
```

Estoy probando con:

```
onmouseover="this.style.boxShadow=inset 0 1px 1px #C27279;"
```

No consigo que se muestre el nuevo estilo.

Comment: **No es posible solo con style**, tendría que recurrir a eventos en _JS_, La mejor opción será usar `CSS` para este propósito. Es poco legible añadir esto en _HTML_ y además atentas contra la Mantenibilidad, reusabilidad y escalabilidad del código.

Comment: Te faltan comillas. Como es un valor "múltiple" (separado con espacios) tienes que ponerle comillas o fallará: `onmouseover="this.style.boxShadow='inset 0 1px 1px #C27279'"` funciona sin problemas (como puedes ver en este [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/okxmt3Lm/)).  Voto por cerrar la pregunta como error tipográfico.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Gracias! Era eso, no me da exactamente el mismo resultado que `:focus` pero algo similar sí que es.

Comment: Perfecto, tenía unos números mal colocados.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Sin embargo, la pregunta original no era a raíz del error tipográfico. Creo que se debería de dejar abierta ya que preguntaba sobre como hacer un focus inline (cosa que es imposible solo con CSS).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No está permitido hacer un `hover` con CSS inline. Sin embargo, siempre puedes usar Javascript para lograrlo mediante `onmouseover` y `onmouseout`.

Ejemplo:

```css
div{
   color: red;
}
```

```html
<div onmouseover='this.style.color="white"' onmouseout='this.style.color="red"'>Esto es un texto</div>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario. Estoy intentando con esto `onmouseover="this.style.box-shadow=inset 0 1px 1px #C27279;,0 0 8px #C27279;"` pero no me funciona.

Comment: @JetLagFox Cuando modificas un estilo con Javascript no puedes usar guiones. Tienes que juntar las dos partes de la propiedad en una, de esta manera: `this.style.boxShadow`.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, aunque no se refleja ningún cambio. No me da ningún error pero no modifica el estilo.

Comment: @JetLagFox No sé si será un error tipográfico al introducirlo pero fíjate que en lo que me has puesto hay esta parte que creo que es errónea: `,0 0 8px #C27279;`

Comment: En principio está bien.

Comment: @JetLagFox ¿Puedes editar la pregunta para ver el código que tienes actualmente?